# global variable in application controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I grap the first country with

```
 @country = Country.find(1)
```

Then i my head navigation i make this loop to get the right tags:

```
%ul.thumbnails
 - @country.tags.find_each(:conditions => "active_house = true") do |a|
     %li.span2
       .thumbnail
         - a.attachments.limit(1).each do |b|
           = image_tag(b.file.url)
         .caption
           %p 
             #{link_to a.url, tag_country_region_houses_path(@country, a.name), :class => 'btn-nav-drop'}
```

This works fine. But the navigation is global so i created a method in application_controller like this:

```
helper_method :tags

def tags
      @country = Country.find(1)
      @tags = @country.tags.find_each(:conditions => "active_house = true")
end
```

And in the navigation view:

```
%ul.thumbnails
  - tags do |a|
      %li.span2
       .thumbnail
         - a.attachments.limit(1).each do |b|
           = image_tag(b.file.url)
         .caption
           %p 
             #{link_to a.url, tag_country_houses_path(@country,  a.name), :class => 'btn-nav-drop '}
```

But i get a error message "no block given (yield)"

Thanks..remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is nothing about global variable which should be avoided whenever possible.

Your problem is in this line

```
tag_country_houses_path(@country,  a.name)
```

There is NO `@country` exists in View.

You may wonder why. The reason is helper can't pass instance variables to View, different from controller.

What your helper all did is to return an array object `@tags`. The value of this object is available in view, but not instance variable `@tags`, neither `@country`.

The fix? Use something to replace `@country`. If the association is country has_many tags, you can do it like this:

```
tag_country_houses_path(a.country,  a.name)
```

If not, you can set a method in tag model to get the country.

And you can even use some `includes` to make query more efficient but that is another story.

Also, your helper can be simplified without assigning any variables.

```
def tags
  Country.find(1).find_each(:conditions => "active_house = true")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_each` accepts a block that will be yielded. Because you write find_each in helper without the block, so it will throw an error. You have two solutions.

Solution1: You can just use find to return an array.

```
def tags
  Country.find(1).tags.find(:all, :conditions => "active_house = true")
end
```

in your view:

```
- tags.each do |t|
  .........
```

Solution2: you can pass the block to your helper.

```
def tags
  Country.find(1).tags.find_each(:conditions => "active_house = true") do |t|
    yield t
  end
end
```

in your view.

```
- tags do |t|
  .........
```

If you have not many many records, just use solution1.